# How do I get Spotlight to find apps in non-standard folders?

Tags: applications, spotlight, search

My work computer has a handful of personal applications that I store not in /Applications, and not in ~/Applications, but in another folder (/usr/local/data/Applications) for several reasons. However, despite this folder being within Spotlight's search index (it's not excluded from Spotlight's index), Spotlight doesn't find the apps there when searching.

Is there any way to address this? Does Spotlight have a preference list property for "list of directories that I know contain apps" or something?

Comment: Spotlight index issues are a common problem.  Have you tried removing the specific folder(s), applying the change, then adding it back?  That's Apple's suggested 1st step for Spotlight index issues.

Comment: yes; and it didn't work. tuberdogg's answer seems like the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a bug report filed with [legacy-homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/4635), it appears that even using the command line to tell Spotlight to index the `/usr/local` hierarchy doesn't work. Apple considers this a system directory and so it won't be indexed.

Comment: In the long thread there, one user suggests one could chmod `/usr/local/whatever` to make it not hidden and findable by spotlight, but I find that dubious -- `/usr/local` and its children (on El Capitain anyway) are already owned by me and are not hidden... and still hidden to Spotlight.

Putting my personal data in `/opt/local/data` or something might be the best way around this problem.